# Include a data file in a document

Tags: apex, bestpractice

I am including a data file (JSON) and am reading the values ​​of it in Apex.
Is this a good practice? Since my data will not change and the settings are too large to be saved in a metadata.

The file is included on the Documents tab.

Comment: if it will not change - why not include it as a static resource? That would be a better approach to be able to access it anywhere.